# Laravel Eloquent Model Return Human value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I Have a `User` model with the property `is_active`.
When i'm inside a foreach loop, I don't want to use the following:
`echo if ( $user->is_active == 0 ) 'not active' : 'active'`

What will be the best way to implement this? write a `isActive()` method on the `User` model and place the logic there?

Comment: Use a presenter for such things. You could also do it with an `accessor`, but I wouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few approaches that you can take.

### Approach 1: [Acessor](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)!

Create on your model:

```
public function getFormattedActiveMethod() {
    return $this->attributes['active'] ? 'active' : 'not active';
}
```

And then you can use it like: `$user->formattedActive` (or whathever you want to call it, as long your method name matches get**CamelCaseName**Attribute()).

You can also add this attribute into the `$appends` property array, so it will show up when you cast the model to array/json.

### Approach 2: Presenter Pattern

Simply create a new class just to present data to your views. It's a good approach to prevent the Model from bloating and also separate your logic.
There are a few packages that helps you to achieve it, like [robclancy/presenter](https://github.com/robclancy/presenter), [laracasts/Presenter](https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter), [ShawnMcCool/laravel-auto-presenter](https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/laravel-auto-presenter) and even [League's Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/), that can help you building a consistent API too.
Depending on the size of your project, it's better to take this approach.